# .predict() runs only on CPU even though GPU is available

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I used [this script to train a model & predict](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) on a machine with GPU installed and enabled and it seems that it's using only the CPU in the prediction stage.

The device placement log I'm seeing during the `.predict()` part is the following:

```
2020-09-01 06:08:19.085400: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op RangeDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.085617: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.089558: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op MapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.090003: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op PrefetchDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.097064: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op FlatMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.097647: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op TensorDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.097802: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.097957: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op ZipDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.101284: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op ParallelMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-09-01 06:08:19.101865: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op ModelDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

even though that when I run:

```
print(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

I receive:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:1', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:2', device_type='GPU')]
```

The code I used [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/georgehdd/4bfd9d6110eefd26821bdcd5bce8c08c). The [full output logs can be seen here](https://gist.github.com/georgehdd/44cc8900024985a7f3ad07de5b969378).

More context:
Python: `3.7.7`
Tensorflow: `2.1.0`
GPU: `Nvidia Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB`
CPU: `Intel Xeon Gold 5218 CPU @ 2.30GHz`
RAM: `394851272 KB`
OS: `Linux`

Comment: What happens if you wrap all the code in a `with tf.device("gpu:0"):` context?

Comment: Then only one operation is placed on the GPU in the prediction. Only this line is performed on the GPU: `PrefetchDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0` and the rest remain on the CPU

Comment: Some ops can only run on the CPU, specially if they are related to data loading which has to happen in the CPU, so I do not see any problem here. Your model is very small and might not see performance increases of using a GPU.

Comment: Is this behavior documented anywhere? also this model takes ~250ms to do a single prediction - wouldn't a GPU make that significantly better?

Comment: That is impossible to say, inference time depends on a lot of things you have not mentioned in the question, including model, amount of computation required by the model, batch size, and how much time it takes to move data between system RAM and GPU. You do not really have evidence that that predict() is running on the CPU, you just assume that it must be faster than currently.

Comment: If you want to read about how ops are created, you can do it here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op , as you can see ops have to be assigned a device explicitly and implemented for that device, and some ops cannot be implemented in a GPU, as I said, specially for data loading.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have a GPU, I assume that `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` returns `True`. You can use this piece of code to force `TensorFlow` to use a specific device-

```py
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    // GPU stuff
```

This also works if you want to force it to use a CPU instead for some part of the code-

```py
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    // CPU stuff
```

An addon which might be helpful while using `tf.device()`, you can use this function to list all the devices you have-

```
def get_available_devices():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos]

get_available_devices()
```

> Though for the use-case you mentioned, I do not guarantee faster inferences with a GPU.

Comment: If I run the prediction inside `tf.device('/gpu:0'):` then only this step in the prediction is performed on the GPU: `PrefetchDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to use a [`Distributed Strategy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) per the docs. Your code would then become something like the following:

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with strategy.scope():
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
            keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(10)
        ]
    )
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam', 
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)

    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
    probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [model, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()]
    )
    probability_model.predict(test_images)
```

Per the documentation, **The best practice for using multiple GPUs is to use tf.distribute.Strategy**.

Comment: I'm trying to use a single GPU here and in inference stage. Thing is that inference is running only on CPU. Training and all uses the GPU flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Your predict function is using GPU. And, I have recalculated timing on NVIDIA 1080 GTX with your code & it is taking 100 ms for inference.

Either reboot the system or check if GPU is getting utilised or not.

Here is the line of your code stating inference is run on GPU:

2020-09-01 06:19:15.885778: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op __inference_distributed_function_58022 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0

Comment: But this line of log is printed out before the `.predict()` function is called. It has nothing to do with the prediction itself. My question was, how can I make the `.predict()` on the GPU as well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the correct tensorflow package? It could help to uninstall tensorflow and install tensorflow-gpu instead.

For documentation see: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: As of Tensorflow 2.1 the CPU+GPU are in the same package, not separate. In addition to this, if it did not install the GPU the video card would not be detected at all.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please call keras from `tensorflow.python`?

Like;

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
```

Also, please check CUDA and CuDNN version. Cuda and CuDNN versions have to be compatible with tensorflow version. You can check from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). As your tensorflow version is `2.1`, CUDA and CuDNN versions are have to be `10.1` & `7.6` respectively.

Comment: Cuda is 10.1 which is compatible. Tensorflow can recognize the GPU but it avoids it during prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a GPU, tf.test.is_gpu_available() should return True. This code forces TensorFlow to utilize a specified device:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```